# How to find all previously-installed Ruby artifacts (files, etc) so I can remove _all_ of them from my OS?

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ruby, previous-versions

Other than the pre-bundled-with-my-default-OS install (eg: `/usr/bin/ruby` on macOS 10.14), I want to completely wipe my OS clean of Ruby before I reinstall Ruby to a "known state." Specifically, I want to better complete steps 1 and 2 from [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199909/605356) that I wrote.

How do I go about figuring this out?

Example Ruby artifacts I've found thus far (in this example, for `macOS 10.14.6`):

1. Any Ruby-related package (eg: `ruby ruby-build rbenv`) installed by [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).
2. Files/dirs from the [version managers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-version-managers.html): `~/.rbenv/ ~/.rvm/`. (Alas, when you do not know how many version managers you might have employed in the past, simply because some random Ruby-application-install procedure suggested you install one and you did not know what you were doing--because again, I'm quite ignorant about the whole Ruby system because I'm just a *user* and not an expert/developer--and now I've got different-version-manager cruft laying around all over the place. This makes for a [rather-difficult predicament](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61196279/605356) when you can't get [Asciidoctor](https://asciidoctor.org/), a Ruby-based app, to run well enough to get your job done.)
3. Other, misc (?) files: `~/.gem ~/.ruby-version` and maybe other things I've not yet found?
4. Other things I've not yet discovered (?).

My OS image is many years (decades?) old (it's been upgraded through many macOS `10.x` upgrades, and the base image has been cloned through many MacBook hardware upgrades) and has acquired a lot of Ruby cruft over that time. Ruby things are (or at least were) broken, and I want to start fresh.

I want to better understand where all these things potential live: files, installed-software packages and any other artifacts related to the engines/platforms/interpreters and `$HOME` files and directories that are typically part of Ruby (and Ruby [version_manager](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/ruby-version-managers.html)-based) installations.

My system runs macOS 10.14.6 and I'm a [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) user. As such, I minimally seek macOS-specific answers. I'm also curious in info that might also apply to Linux, since my team and I also run many Ubuntu and other Linux installations.

Comment: How do you define Ruby files, packages, and other artifacts? Dollar coins (easily sterilizable) to doughnuts and hold the stakes in my mouth, it will come down to a Bug Hunt for type A objects + type B objects + type C objects.... ad nauseam.

Comment: Good question. As what's noted above: steps 1 and 2 from [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61199909/605356) provide much (most?) of the context. In general: _I wish I knew_ what all to look for, but since I'm not a Ruby wizard (and no one will tell me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61196279/605356)) I'm "fumbling in the dark without a flashlight." I'll update the question with some examples.

Comment: @K7AAY - artifact examples provided in a question edit I just submitted. Does this provide what you need when you ask _"How do you define Ruby files, packages, and other artifacts?"_

Comment: Good suggestion. Been there. ServerFault.com and StackOverlow.com, too. I also just posted [a pointer to here from reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/g2qtsb/how_to_find_all_previouslyinstalled_ruby/).